# How to use where not between in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am try
ing to get something like this

```
select * from `users`
inner join `settings`
    on `users`.`id` = `settings`.`user_id`
    and NOW() NOT BETWEEN quit_hour_start AND quit_hour_end
where `notification_key` != ''
    and `device_type` = 'Android'
```

in eloquent. Does anyone try and get success to build this query in eloquent.
I know I can use `\DB::select(DB::raw());` and get my result. But I want to use ie with Laravel eloquent method.

====== update comment for tried queries========

```
$androidUser = User::join('settings', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'settings.user_id')
        ->where(DB::raw("'$currentTime' NOT BETWEEN quit_hour_start AND quit_hour_end"));
    })
    ->where('notification_key', '!=', '')
    ->where('device_type' ,'=', 'Android')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried to write to do this with Eloquent? Or is this a simple _do it for me_

Comment: yes sure please check updated question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereNotBetween('votes', [1, 100]) // For one column
                ->whereRaw("? NOT BETWEEN quit_hour_start AND quit_hour_end", [$currentTime]) // Use whereRaw for two columns

                ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries, or you can rewrite as to wheres

Comment: Yes, I checked but need different columns(quit_hour_start, quit_hour_end) NOT BETWEEN quit_hour_start AND quit_hour_end.