# Laravel Query: get models where child's date ranges is not in array of date ranges

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have `Event` model that `hasMany` childs `Time` models. 
 `Time` is a datetime range that has `start_time` and `end_time` fields.

How to get all `Events` where none of childs `Times` crossing with an `array` of date ranges?

Example:

```
$events = Event::notInDateRange([
    [ 'start_date' => '2000.01.01 00:00:00', 'end_date' => '2000.01.01 12:00:00' ],
    [ 'start_date' => '2000.01.02 12:00:00', 'end_date' => '2000.01.02 16:00:00' ],
    [ 'start_date' => '2000.01.03 10:00:00', 'end_date' => '2000.01.03 12:30:00' ],
])->get();
// In this case I don't want to get Event where one of Time is 
// [ 'start_date' => '2000.01.03 12:00:00' => 'end_date' => '2000.01.03 14:00:00' ]
```

Comment: You can use 'where not between' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406790/how-to-use-where-not-between-in-laravel-5-5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use where not between in Laravel 5.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406790/how-to-use-where-not-between-in-laravel-5-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes) to create a `notInDateRange` scope in your `Event` model and use the `whereNotBetween` [where clause](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses) inside the new scope.

Inside your `Event` model class, define a new function called `scopeNotInDateRange` that accepts a start and end date and define it as follows:

```
public function scopeNotInDateRange($query, $start_date, $end_date)
    $start = new Carbon($start_date);
    $end = new Carbon($end_date);
    return $query->whereNotBetween('start_date', [$start, $end])
                 ->whereNotBetween('end_date', [$start, $end]);
```

Also remember to add `use Carbon\Carbon;` to the top of your `Event` class. We will use Carbon to convert strings to dates.

You could then use your new query scope like `App\Event::notInDateRange($start, $end)`. You can also chain scopes, so in your example you could use:

```
$events = Event::notInDateRange('2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2000-01-01 12:00:00')
               ->notInDateRange('2000-01-02 12:00:00', '2000-01-02 16:00:00')
               ->notInDateRange('2000-01-03 10:00:00', '2000-01-03 12:30:00')
               ->get();
```

Note that I also changed the `.`'s you used in your dates to `-`'s so that Carbon would be able to convert the strings to dates.

If you haven't yet, also ensure that your `start_date` and `end_date` columns are converted to Carbon dates using [Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) when you use access their values in Laravel. To do this, add the following snippet to your `Event` model class:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'start_date', 'end_date'
];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But you miss the thing that `Event` model doesn't have any time fields. `Event` hasMany childs models `Time` which has `start_time` and `end_time`

Comment: In that case you could use `whereDoesntHave`, like `$events = App\Event::whereDoesntHave('times', function ($query) {
    $query->whereBetween('start_date', [new Carbon('2000-01-01 00:00:00'), new Carbon('2000-01-01 12:00:00']))
               ->orWhereBetween('end_date', [new Carbon('2000-01-01 00:00:00'), new Carbon('2000-01-01 12:00:00']))
              ->orWhereBetween('start_date', [new Carbon('2000-01-02 00:00:00'), new Carbon('2000-01-02 12:00:00']))
              ->...etc,`